# Java - array size not updating

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

Read whole numbers from a user, then display the list of numbers input and the frequency of each value. The number of inputs should vary from 1-30, and the values accept 0-9.

My issue is that the array always defaults to 1 even if I change it to `int[] numbers = new int[numInputs];`. It appears that `numInputs` gets written over to 1 during the first `for` loop but even changing the value of `numInputs` it still caps out at 1. I'm sure my logic is wrong but I'm not sure where.

```
public class Occurrence
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //variables
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numInputs = 1, temp;
        int[] numbers = new int[31];
        int[] count = new int[31];
        boolean success = false;

        //start of program
        System.out.println("How many input values [max:30]?");

        //while no valid input
        while (!success)
        {
            try
            {
                numInputs = keyboard.nextInt(); //get a number
                numInputChecker(numInputs);     //is it valid?
                success = true;                 //ok

            }
            catch (Exception e)                 //else get a new number
            {
                keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Whole numbers 1 through 30 only, please.");

            }
        }
        //reset the loop checker
        success = false;

        //read numbers to fill that array
        System.out.println("Enter " + numInputs + " numbers.");

        for(int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)     //from 0 to max number
        {
            while (!success)                   //while no valid number
            {
                try
                {
                    numbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();    //fill the current cell with a number
                    numberChecker(numbers[i]);          //is it valid?
                    success = true;                     //ok
                }
                catch (Exception e)                     //else get a new number
                {
                    keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Whole numbers 0 through 9 only, please.");
                }
            }
        }

       //take the input and count each use of element
        for (int i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++)     //for 0 to max number
        {
            temp = numbers[i];  //get the current value of the cell
            count[temp]++;      //add the use of that value to a new array's cell
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)   //from 0 to 9 (expected)
        {

            if (count[i] > 0 && count[i] == 1)  //if cell not empty
            {
                System.out.println(i + " " + count[i]);  //print the current cell and how many times it was used
            }
        }

    }

    static void numInputChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 1) || (integer > 30))    //if 0 or negative, or if 31+
        {
            throw new Exception();              //say no
        }
    }

    static void numberChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 0) || (integer > 9)) //if negative or 10+
        {
            throw new Exception();          //say no
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic is broken at the second cycle where you do feel up an array, because success variable isn't reset for a subsequent while loops. It's quite easy to fix it as such:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)     //from 0 to max number
    {
        while (!success)                   //while no valid number
        {
            try {
                numbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();    //fill the current cell with a number
                numberChecker(numbers[i]);          //is it valid?
                success = true;                     //ok
            } catch (Exception e)                     //else get a new number
            {
                keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Whole numbers 0 through 9 only, please.");
            }
        }
        success = false; // [amsilf]: That's the cycle reset
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, `java.util.NoSuchElementException` occurs and catches the error handling the block.

Use `keyboard.hasNextInt()` before `keyboard.nextInt()`.

Like this!

```
try {
   keyboard.hasNext(); // here!
   numInputs = keyboard.nextInt(); //get a number
   numInputChecker(numInputs);     //is it valid?
   success = true;                 //ok
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last for loop should be that

```
    for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)   //from 0 to 31(expected)
    {

        if (count[i] > 0)  //if cell not empty
        {
            System.out.println(i + " " + count[i]);  //print the current cell and how many times it was used
        }
    }
```